# Networking icons on the top panel in 19.10

Tags: networking, icons, 19.10

On my notebook, when my WiFi is connected, I see a Wifi icon in the panel. When I plug in the Ethernet, the Wifi icon is replaced by an Ethernet icon. Hence, both networks are active but only one icon at a time is shown. Should not BOTH WiFi and Ethernet icons be visible when both connections are active? Seems reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: Think both connections might be available, but only one is in use.  Ethernet usually has higher priority over wifi.  If you disable ethernet in network manager then wifi icon comes back

Comment: Notebooks rely on batteries and therefore when the power-conserving Ethernet is attached, WiFi is customarily superceded. Why do you want to see both?

Comment: Maybe they're on different subnets? Maybe they're both consuming battery? Or perhaps just a reminder that both are active. Thank you for your replies. Although I do wish both icons were visible when both interfaces are active.